# Magento 2 : Product Prices

Tags: magento2, price, multistore

In Magento 2

What is the difference between between below price types ?

- Price
- Original Price
- Special Price
- Final Price
- Regular Price

How they are differ from each other & what are their uses in a multi store site ?

Comment: Any details to add ?

Answer (score 1):

**Price** - The product price after considering catalog price rules, group prices, special prices, tier prices, product option prices but before calculating taxes and shopping cart price rules).

**Original Price** - The product price before any calculations (catalog price rules, group prices, special prices, tier prices, product option prices).

**Special Price** - A special price can be offered for a designated period of time. During the specified time period, the special price appears instead of the regular price

**Final Price** - The final price is the total price of products and depends on each product type.

**Regular price** - Regular price is the product’s original price which is used to calculate discounts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, any key difference in Price & Regular price ?